# String and ? : operators

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I have to build query string from string values like:

```
connString += "INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ( "+

_cd.userName "," +

//and there i'd like to use ?: operators:

_cd.lastLogin == "Null" ? "null" : _cd.lastLogin ","
```

So my query would look like `INSERT INTO (...) VALUES ('name', null, (...))`

But when Im using that it cuts my string, so it's look like

```
",null,1,2,'name', (...)";
```

Well, I know that I can use var a,b,c,d and then check if `(_cd.lastLogin == "Null) a = null` and put that into string, but there is many variables.

What is proper way to use it?

@EDIT: 
Code:

```
string query =  "INSERT INTO PersonLogin(...) " + Environment.NewLine +
 "VALUES (" + _cD.userID + ","
 + "'" + _cD.number + "',"
 + "'" + _cD.dateCreate + "','"
 + _cD.lastLogin == "Null" ? ",null," : _cD.lastLogin + "',"
 + _cD.taken + ","
 + _cD.canLogin + ""+ Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot - C#.

Comment: The proper way is to use SqlParameters. Building your queries like this is madness.

Comment: What Arran said. But to answer your question, probably put parentheses around all usages of `? :`.

Comment: Ok, but textCommand will give me queries like INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (@par1, @par2) right? I need to create string with queries (from 10+ tables) and then send and execute that string as script in database in another server.

Comment: @user13657 The SQL client might be able to to a batch of operations like that. Even if not I'd just send the commands separately in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` operator has lower precedence then `+` operator. So you need to parenthesize around the usage of `?` and `:`.

```
connString += ... + (_cd.lastLogin == "Null" ? "null" :"'"+ _cd.lastLogin) +"'" ...;
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting the wrong way of implementation. See msm2020 answer.

Comment: @AmitRanjan I'm not suggesting this, I'm trying to show OP his mistake.

Comment: I'll mark as solution, becaouse that's answer for my question, but well, as You all said - i'll try to do it with SqlCommand.

Answer (score 2):

you can use SqlParameter and set value with DbNull.Value

> INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (@par1, @par2) 
>     command.Parameters.AddwithValue("@par1",DbNull.Value)

Comment: I know that I can use SqlParameters and Command. But as I said i have tables with 50+ colums and for example only 20/50 are null. So with this solution i will need to do something like if(value == null) then add nullValue else add value.value

Comment: you can loop in command.parameters but this a bad solution
OR 

+ _cD.lastLogin == null ? ",null," : _cD.lastLogin + "',"

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to make your queries is **not building your queries with string**, but using SqlParameters. This will give your more readable code and is better protected against sql injection.